# Sort List<List<string>> by length in ascending order

Tags: c#

May I know how to sort `List<List<string>>` by the length of `List<string>` in ascending order?

Comment: Please help me for the -2 if you think this question is helpful to you :)

Answer (score 22):

`var result = list.OrderBy(x => x.Length)`

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the [List<T>.Sort method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx):

```
listOfListOfStrings.Sort((a, b) => a.Length.CompareTo(b.Length));
```

Alternatively, you can create an IEnumerable<List<string>> from the List<List<string>> that returns the lists in sorted order when enumerated, but leaves the original list untouched:

```
IEnumerable<List<string>> result = listOfListOfStrings.OrderBy(x => x.Length);
```